# Reset password on WordPress deployed to Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, smtp

I have created a WordPress site on Windows Azure using the gallery.

I understand that Azure sites do not have SMTP capabilities.

How do I do a password reset on a WordPress site if it can't send email? I know that I can specify an SMTP server (like Gmail) in the WordPress settings and/or with a WordPress plugin. But I have to be able to login to do that.

It seems like WordPress site installs from the gallery are not completely functional because of the lack of a password reset option. Is there any other way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you currently locked out of a WP site? If you aren't, but are just thinking ahead, I don't understand why you can't set up an external SMTP server?

Comment: :( I got locked out of WP too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you could use SMTP on WordPress in Azure by adding a plugin for configure the SMTP service. These are two of the plugins you can find. Personally i have tested configure-smtp and is working very well. Give a try to it and leave feedback.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/configure-smtp/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is access to your wordpress administration - so that you can install additional plugins that will give you the option you lack then you can update your password dirctly in the database.
see this codex page:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_MySQL_Command_Line
Starting with MySQL version 5.x you can also run this command:

```
"UPDATE (name-of-table-you-found) SET user_pass = MD5('"(new-password)"') WHERE ID = (id#-of-account-you-are-reseting-password-for);" (actually changes the password)
```

also this page has some info about azure and sending e-mails:
[How can i send an Email using PHP at windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582492/how-can-i-send-an-email-using-php-at-windows-azure)