# Email sending is not working in Adobe muse site hosted in Azure?

Tags: php, email, azure, muse

Hello All,

```
         We have a site that made in Adobe muse , When we try to publish to Azure  it giving a error Email not configured (http://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-3581, http://forums.adobe.com/message/5822297), and  reason was azure not provide email service ( SendGrid not available in our region ) .
```

I see some other post that provide the way to put send mail in site but it not working ([How can i send an Email using PHP at windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582492/how-can-i-send-an-email-using-php-at-windows-azure), http://glob.com.au/sendmail/ ,http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail) can you provide any solution for this problem . Very argent , because we already spend two day on this error . we have to release our sit as soon as possible .

with regards ,

jophy

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue with Windows azure 
SendGrid is not available and tried all other methods including the one above